# Disabling the ability to increase length of an event - Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have searched through the full calendar documentation and tried a couple of solutions but nothing has worked. I am using full calendar within a website that renders events into it using JSON. Editable is set to true to enable users to alter the date of a position. However, regardless of setting disableResizing to false, the events can still be dragged from the right to extend them across multiple days.

How do I definitively disable this function, and do so without it effecting the current ability to drag and move events to different days. Any help on this would be great.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I think the key may be here 'regardless of setting disableResizing to false'.  I think you may want to set disableResizing to true!

Comment: Haha ahh man that is a such a rookie mistake. My apologies for wasting your time, but thanks all the same for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless make sure that options that have true/false values are not strings "true"/"false", or else somthings might not work like allDay option for events.

Doesnt work:

```
allDay:"true"
```

Work's

```
allDay:true
```